# I have one input field with max length 2 and if I enter 0 - 9 values it should give 01,02 etc and for above 10 it should give same values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`enter code here`

```
                               <Field
                                  type="text"
                                  maxLength="2"
                                  minLength="2"
                                  name={`transactions.goodsMovements.transactionItems[${index}].transactionLineItems[${i}].realizeNumber`}
                                  id={`transactions.goodsMovements.transactionItems[${index}].transactionLineItems[${i}].realizeNumber`}
                                  style={{ minWidth: 46 }}
                                  onChange={e =>
                                    handleNumericInputChange1(
                                      e,
                                      setFieldValue
                                    )
                                  }
                                  className="form-control"
                                />



       const handleNumericInputChange1 = (e, setFieldValue) => {
            let val = ("0" + e.target.value).slice(-2)
             setFieldValue(e.target.name, val);}
```

For above code it I enter 0-9 it will give double digit but I'm unable to enter digits after 9

Comment: Can't you just add a simple condition to check whether `e.target.value` is `< 9` and then slice and add zeros?

Comment: _“but I'm unable to enter digits after 9”_ - what do you mean by that, exactly? If I reproduce basically what you have here, but in normal HTML & JS, I can not figure out what the problem is supposed to be regarding the value 9 …?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padStart()`

```
const handleNumericInputChange1 = (e, setFieldValue) => {
            let val = String(e.target.value).padStart(2, '0');
             setFieldValue(e.target.name, val);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't enter 10+ because each time you type a single digit your function pads it with a zero and updates the value. Then the value is 2-digits and the field is maxed out, you can't type a second digit because it would actually be a third digit.

`minLength=2` is fine, but remove the `maxLength` because your change handler is already enforcing a max.

Comment: the condition is shouldn't enter more than 2 digits so if we enter between 1 - 9 it should be   01 - 09 , and we can also add 10 - 99,is the any solution for that